# Los registros siempre señalan hacia el mismo id

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando hacer un sistema de comentarios.. Digamos que ya tengo las "publicaciones" y se puede comentar estas, pero cuando añado un comentario siempre se añade en el ultimo registro, da igual desde donde lo añada, siempre se añaden en la ultima publicación...

```
<?php

    $tabla = NULL;


    if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
        switch ($_GET["lang"]) {
            case 'es':
                $tabla = "mensajes";
                break;
            case 'en':
                $tabla = "mensajesEN";
                break;
            case 'it':
                $tabla = "mensajesIT";
                break;
            case 'fr':
                $tabla = "mensajesFR";
                break;
            case 'ger':
                $tabla = "mensajesGER";
                break;
        }

    } else {
        $tabla = "mensajes";
    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY id DESC ";
    if($resultado = $mysqli->query($sql)) {

        while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {

            $id_padre = $fila["id"];

            ?>

            <div class='cajaCont'>
                <div class='col-12 comentario'>
                    <input name="id" type="hidden" value="'<?php echo $fila["id"]; ?>"/>
                    <img src="avatars/<?php echo $fila["avatar"]; ?>" alt="avatar">
                    <p><span class="<?php echo $fila["color"];?>"> <?php echo $fila["usuario"];?>: </span> <?php echo $fila["mensaje"];?> </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-12 numComentarios">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalComentario"><i class="far fa-keyboard"></i> <?php echo $lang["btn7"]; ?></a>
                        <a id="text1" href="#"><i class='far fa-comments'></i> <?php echo $lang["comentarios"]; echo " (" . randComentarios() . ")"; ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php


            $sqlcomentarios = "SELECT * FROM comentarios WHERE id_padre = '$id_padre' ORDER BY id DESC";
            if($resulComentarios = $mysqli->query($sqlcomentarios)) {

                while($filaC = $resulComentarios->fetch_assoc()) {

                    ?>

                        <div class="cajaCont comment1" id="comment1">
                            <div class="col-10 comentarioHijo">
                                <p><span class="<?php echo $fila["color"]; ?>"> <?php echo $filaC["usuario"]; ?></span> <?php echo $filaC["mensaje"]; ?></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php

                }
            }

            ?>

            <div class="cajaCont comment1" id="comment1"">
                <div class="col-10 comentarioHijo">
                    <a class="dejarComment" href="" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalComentario">Deja un comentario</a>

                </div>

            <div class="modal fade" id="modalComentario" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalComentario" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="modaltitle">
                                <?php echo $lang["btn7"]; ?>
                            </h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">

                            <form method="POST" action="sendComment.php">
                                <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="<?php echo $id_padre; ?>">
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="usernameComment" placeholder="<?php echo $lang["user"]; ?>">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <textarea class="form-control" name="text" id="textareaComment" rows="3" placeholder="<?php echo $lang["mensaje"]; ?>" maxlength="1500"></textarea>
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group row">
                                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                                        <button type="submit" name="sendComentario" id="sendComentario" class="btn btn-primary"><?php echo $lang["btn6"]; ?></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>

                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
                                <?php echo $lang["btn3"]; ?></button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            </div>

            <?php

        }

        $resulComentarios->free();
        $resultado->free();


    }

?>
```

Página que procesa el formulario:

```
<?php

    include "conexion.php";

    $username   = NULL;
    $text       = NULL;
    $tabla      = NULL;

    if(isset($_GET["lang"])){
        switch ($_GET["lang"]) {
            case 'es':
                $tabla = "comentarios";
                break;
            case 'en':
                $tabla = "comentarios";
                break;
            case 'it':
                $tabla = "comentarios";
                break;
            case 'fr':
                $tabla = "comentarios";
                break;
            case 'ger':
                $tabla = "comentarios";
                break;
        }

    } else {
        $tabla = "comentarios";
    }

    if(isset($_POST["sendComentario"])) {
        $username   = strip_tags($_POST["username"]);
        $text       = strip_tags($_POST["text"]);
        $id_padre   = $_POST["hidden"];

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO $tabla (id, id_padre, usuario, mensaje) VALUES (NULL, '$id_padre', '$username', '$text')";
        $mysqli->query($sql2);
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

?>
```

El formulario está dentro de un modal, al rellenarlo inserta bien los datos en la taba, pero apunta a la id del padre incorrecta.

Cada publicación si muestra los comentarios que son suyos, pero al añadirlos no lo hace donde debe...

La variable a la que le llega el id incorrecto es `$id_padre` que viene de un campo **hidden** del formulario.

¿Qué se me está pasando?

Comment: No entiendo mucho tu lógica, sobre todo por qué tienes dos `SELECT` uno dentro de  otro y dentro de un `while` ¿? ¿Qué hace el primer `SELECT` y qué hace el segundo? ¿Por qué no haces uno solo uniendo las tablas con `JOIN`? ¿Verificaste qué dato se guarda en `hidden` (me refiero al HTML)?

Comment: Respecto a la lógica, no se realizarlo de otra manera la verdad, en el campo hidden siempre se guarda la id del ultimo registro que acaba mostrándolo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Mi lógica es la siguiente: muestro los datos por el while, y como necesito usar esos datos dentro de la siguiente consulta, la hago y dentro del otro while donde muestro los datos de la segunda consulta pongo los datos de la anterior que necesito.

Comment: Para añadir los comentarios tengo la siguiente tabla @A.Cedano 
id, id_padre, usuario, mensaje
Se inserta todo bien, pero el dato que le llega a id_padre siempre es la id del la ultima publicación, por lo que los comentarios siempre se agregan en el ultimo registro...este lo envio por el campo hidden del formulario, pero no se donde tengo el fallo

Answer (score 0):

¿Como tienes el modal?
Debes de tener un modal para cada uno de los formularios(que no te lo recomiendo) o tener un solo modal con solo un formulario y capturar y enviar la información con jquery.

Comment: EL formulario funciona bien, envía todos los datos y os inserta en la bbdd, solo que el dato $id_padre, no llega con el id correcto, siempre llega con el id del último registro que muestra, por lo que es como si siempre se pusieran los comentarios en la ultima publicacion